# Отсутствие гласных в славянских языках

Tags: славянизмы, фонетика

Когда пишут старославянские слова, часто после согласных ставят твердый знак. Вот, например, из объяснения слова "портной" в одном из предыдущих вопросов: "Портной – от пъртный шьвьцо, где пъртъ – одежда".
В сербском языке и сейчас много слов почти без гласных - то же название страны "Србия". А в Адриатическом море есть остров Крк (не помню только, какой из стран бывшей Югославии он принадлежит).
Мне стало интересно: неужели малое количество гласных - это характерная особенность славянских языков? И как же это все произносилось?

Answer (score 5):

Во
 всех приведенных вами словах гласные есть. Гласные "ь" и "ъ" до сих 
есть в русском языке, первую мы можем услышать на конце слова 
"вест**и**", а вторую на конце слова "плетк**а**". Сейчас эти звуки 
возможны лишь в слабых позициях, но раньше они могли быть и ударными.

Что касается "Србиа" и "Крк", то тут звук [р] произносится с большей 
силой и по сути выполняет роль гласной. В русском подобная функция у "р" может 
  наблюдаться в "мудрствуя" и в словах с приставкой "чрез-"